# Program Crashes unsure why

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Hello i'm trying to make a simple program to change the background colour on key press but it just crashes. It's to do with my loop but i don't really understand why it crashes.

thanks

```
import sys, pygame, random, time
from threading import Thread
pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 100, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
Colour = (0,0,0)
size = width, height = 350, 350
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

Running = True
while True:
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: # Escape key
        Running = False
    elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
        print("down")
        Colour = red

    elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
        print("h")
        Colour = black

    elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
        Colour = green

        print("h")
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key       
        Colour = white

        print("h")

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height))       
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Any particular error message when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing. The window just stops responding. That's what i don't get.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a way for pygame to know if you want to quit the window.  Instead of doing `key = pygame.key.get_pressed()` use:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit 
        if event.key == K_UP:
            Colour = black
        if event.key == K_DOWN:
            Colour = red
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            Colour = white
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            Colour = green
```

You also need a way for the program to handle time e.g. not run faster than you can see.  You can do this by setting this variable at the top of your code:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

and running this at the very end of your `while` loop:

```
clock.tick(FPS)
```

where you set the FPS as a number equal to the desired frames per second.

You can also remove your `Running = True` variable from the program.  That should be all you need to get it running.  Good luck!  Ask questions below.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

You have a bug: the while loop while go forever because you are testing `while True` instead of `while Running`. You could change to `while Running` or after testing for escape key, you could `break` to exit the while loop.

Also, all pygame examples I have looked up just now have an event checker. Without that, pygame freezes. If you add it, everything is smooth.

Here are both of those corrected:

```
import sys, pygame, time
pygame.init()

size = 350, 350
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

Running = True
while Running:  # <----- changed this from True to Running
    time.sleep(0.03)  # avoid blasting the CPU. I think pygame.time.Clock also exists

    # this makes pygame responsive
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False  # <---- or you could just break

    # from here is as you originally wrote
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        print('exit')
        Running = False  # <---- or you could just break

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```